# Updating data not working. No error but the data do not change

Tags: php

I'm stuck for whole day because thinking about the update data problem. There was no error, when click update, it's successful but the data not updating.
Here is my index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Daftar Mahasiswa</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$sambung = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Gagal konek ke server.");
mysql_select_db("kuih2") or die ("Gagal membuka database.");
?>
```

the table for view the data...

```
<table border="5">
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Total Item</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th colspan="3">Aksi</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $query = "select * from itemorder";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $sambung);
    //$no = 0;
    while ($buff = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //$no++;
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $buff['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $buff['item']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $buff['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $buff['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $buff['contact']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $buff['totalitem']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $buff['total']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $buff['id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="hapus.php?id=<?php echo $buff['id']; ?>">Hapus</a></td>
    </tr>
```

another code...

```
<?php
    }
    mysql_close($sambung);
    ?>
    </table>
    <p align="left"><a href="tambah.html">Tambah Data</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

update.php code

```
<?php
include("koneksi.php");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$totalitem = $_POST['totalitem'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
$query = mysql_query("update itemorder set item='$item', name='$name', address='$address',contact='$contact', totalitem='$totalitem, total='$total' where id='$id'");
echo "Data Telah diupdate<br>
<a href=\"index.php\">Kembali</a>";
?>
```

edit.php code

```
<?php
 $sambung = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Gagal konek ke server.");
mysql_select_db("kuih2") or die ("Gagal membuka database.");
//$edit=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mhs WHERE nim='$_GET[nim]'");
//$r_edit=mysql_fetch_array($edit);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "select * from itemorder where id='$id'";
$result =  mysql_query($query, $sambung) or die("gagal melakukan query");
     $buff = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                 mysql_close($sambung);
?>
<html>
<head><title>Edit Data</title></head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $buff['id']; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Item</td><td><input type="text" name="item" value="<?php echo $buff['item']; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $buff['name']; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address</td><td><input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $buff['address']; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact</td><td><input type="text" name="contact" value="<?php echo $buff['contact']; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Total Item</td><td><input type="text" name="totalitem" value="<?php echo $buff['totalitem']; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Total</td><td><input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $buff['total']; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr>
<input value="Simpan" type="submit" name="submit"/>
<input type="button" value="Kembali" onClick="self.history.back()"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not checking anywhere to see if your queries worked - add `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of each `mysql_query()` call to see if there are any problems.

Comment: Try `mysql_query("update itemorder set item='$item', name='$name', address='$address',contact='$contact', totalitem='$totalitem, total='$total' where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());` to see the error.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER the error is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RM2' where id='67'' at line 1

Comment: Probably "one" of potentially other mistakes. `totalitem='$totalitem,` using error reporting would've helped you spot this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, absolutely.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a comma. You wrote:

```
totalitem='$totalitem,
```

but it should be:

```
totalitem='$totalitem',
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a typo error in update.php, instead of totalitem='$totalitem' you have 
totalitem='$totalitem....it happens all the time.Hope this helps